# Multiple buttons with overlay fade in/out trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have blocks with a trigger and overlay.

Here's an example jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/uRstt/7/

When the overlay fade effect is triggered on a specific block I want the overlay on other blocks to fade Out. also if you click the trigger on a block with an active overlay, it has to fade out.

Here's code of what I'm trying to achieve without success.

```
$(".trigger").click(function(){
  !$(this).parent().find(".overlay").fadeOut();
  $(this).parent().find(".overlay").stop(true,true).fadeToggle();
});
```

---

**Here's the correct code thanks to Adeneo**

```
$(".trigger").click(function(){
   $(this).siblings(".overlay").stop(true,true).fadeToggle().closest('.container').siblings().find('.overlay').fadeOut();
});
```

Here's an example of a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uRstt/8/)

Comment: like this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/uRstt/8/) ???

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
$(".trigger").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings(".overlay").stop(true,true).fadeToggle()
    .closest('.container').siblings().find('.overlay').fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: This does not work correctly. If you click on the triggered button to fade it out it does nothing. Adeneo has the perfect solution. Check my Question. It includes the correct solution.

Comment: @404notfound I know it's kinda naughty but I changed my answer just to not cause mistakes and let the correct answer for your question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, something like this should work:

```
$(".trigger").click(function(){
    $(this).next().stop(true,true).fadeToggle();
    $(this).parent().siblings().children('.overlay:visible').fadeOut();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uRstt/9/

Comment: This works with the example, but not with my code for some reason. Adeneo has a solution that works with my code. Thanks